# ¿como hacer uso de la clase Gson en android?

Tags: java, android

tengo una duda, estoy intentando usar el ejemplo para poder guardar con "Gson",pero a la hora de usar esta linea:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //Instancia Gson.
```

me marca error y no me detecta la clase "Gson" ni tampoco me deja improtarla, alguien me puede decir como hacer uso de esta clase?

Comment: Importa la libreria en tu proyecto y luego Gson en tu clase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ello debes implementar la librería en tu `build.gradle`:

```
 dependencies {
      //aqui hay otras dependencias
     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
  }
```

dar clic en `Sync Now`:

Answer (score 0):

En el gradle debes poner

```
dependencies {
     ...
     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
     ...
}
```